# Infinite black hole mass

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, black-holes, time-dilation

If a black hole has infinite mass, then how come a black grows or there are different kind of sizes of black holes?

It appears to me there is indeed a maximum compression of the mass inside the event horizon, and above that the hole cannot do anything else but expand.

I'm curious how this would work in relation to Carlo Rovelli's view on a black hole. (Wich states that a black hole is actually going to explode, but due to the immense size of gravity there is a serious time dilation of billions of years before we could actually see it explode from the outside)

Comment: A black hole does not have infinite mass

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a misunderstanding. As already pointed out in the comments, a black hole does not have infinite mass. In fact, the "size" of the black hole (to be precise, the radius of the [event horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon) since the actual singularity is believed to be point-like), is directly related to the black hole's mass (and only to the mass, since all the other terms are constants) by

$$r=\frac{2Gm}{c^2}$$

which is the [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) or radius of the event horizon for a [non-rotating black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric). Thus, if the mass $m$ increases, $r$ increases as well.

But you are right that there is something infinite about black holes, which is the curvature of spacetime – since a singularity is believed to contain all of the black hole's mass in a point (which is infinitely small, or rather, has no spatial dimension), the density and thus curvature becomes infinite.

However, one should note at this point that only in General Relativity this infinity occurs which is one of the reasons it is believed that GR cannot be used to describe a singularity. Instead, a theory of [quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity) would be needed.

Comment: The need for a singularity, in explanations of the observed astrophysical effects of black holes, is already avoided thru Einstein-Cartan Theory, developed by 1929 thru conversations between Einstein & the mathematician Elie Cartan, 14 years after GR & a few yrs. after the discovery of particulate spin: ECT's more hypothetical cosmological consequences, torsion-based and consistent with the CMB, are explored in numerous papers written or co-authored between 2010 and 2020 by Nikodem Poplawski, whose preprints are freely available and can be found by his name on the "Arxiv" site.